# React Mobx with MST: Refresh token implement logic

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I come from Redux and I start to learn MST.

I try to introduce the logic of Token's refreshing professionally. I have already explained what it is supposed to:

1. Client sends a request to the server
2. Server answers every 60s code 401
3. Client knows that when it is 401, it has to refresh token, send the request for refresh token
4. Client after receiving a positive response from the server, is to repeat the action earlier.

For rectification, I use Boilerplate from Ignited (React-Native):

```
export const AuthenticationStoreModel = types
  .model("AuthenticationStore")
  .props({
    isAuthenticationed: types.optional(types.boolean, false),
  })
  .extend(withEnvironment)
  .extend(withRootStore)
  .actions((self) => ({
    setAuthenticated(value: boolean) {
      self.isAuthenticationed = value
    },

    refreshToken: flow(function* () {
      const authenticationApi = new AuthenticationApi(self.environment.api)
      const result: RefreshTokenResult = yield authenticationApi.refreshToken()

      if (result.kind === "ok") {
        return true
      } else {
        __DEV__ && console.tron.log(result.kind)
        return false
      }
    }),
  }))
  .actions((self) => ({
    logout: flow(function* () {
      const authenticationApi = new AuthenticationApi(self.environment.api)
      const result: LogoutResult = yield authenticationApi.logout()

      if (result.kind === "ok") {
        self.setAuthenticated(false)
      } else if (result.kind === "unauthorized") {
        const result = yield self.refreshToken()

        if (result) {
          self.rootStore.authenticationStore.logout()
        }
      } else {
        __DEV__ && console.tron.log(result.kind)
      }
    }),
  }))
```

Well it works, but it's poorly written. How am I supposed to improve it? Can't do some middleware under it?

and how do I do some dependency injection for the AuthenticationApi() class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of Ignite and MobX-State-Tree.

I would recommend putting this retry logic into your AuthenticationApi class, rather than in the MST model. You might be able to use Axios directly to do this or work with apisauce.

In terms of dependency injection for the AuthenticationApi class, your code seems fine. Just inject anything you need here:

```
const authenticationApi = new AuthenticationApi(self.environment.api, otherDeps, etc)
```

Comment: where do I need to call refreshToken as we have to monitor all auth Api calls? Can you please guide to a level.